# TFS 2013 with Git not showing file history

Tags: git, tfs

we've recently recovered from an outage which left our TFS 2013 Update 4 instance a little worse for wear.  We had to recover a Git repo from peoples local clones (which worked great by the way) but now for that Repo we're not seeing any history for most of the files, instead we're getting the following:

> We are currently processing some of your commits.  This result set may not be complete.  Please try again later.

The server has had 3 days so far to process this and it doesn't seem to be moving any further forward.

Does anyone know how to force the process to kick off or if there is a service I should be looking for to see if it has stopped?

Comment: You need to raise a support call with MSFT for this! It is not normal...

Comment: I have had this issue for a bit but it disappeared after 5 mins.

Comment: @HamidShahid it seems with 2013 that the DB can get a bit stuck, since we've moved to TFS 2015 we've not had any repeat of the isse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a separate issue on the box relating to a corrupt Git repository (a different one) where we were getting an error "TF400714: File ID 0 not found".  We resolved this on a support call with Microsoft (incidentally the issues which resulted in this error are handled with TFS 2015) and following that everything else just started to work again.